# Android Error Reporting - without Google Play

Tags: android

My application is not on Google Play. 
Is there a way to send the error report from LogCat to an email/server database, when the application crashing?

How?

Thanks,
Leslie

Comment: Try http://code.google.com/p/acra/ library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra), it allows you to automatically handle crashes and link that to bug trackers.

Answer (score 0):

I use [hockeyapp](http://hockeyapp.net/) for my work.Easy to distribute and managing versions and there is a crash reporter that send you the logcat trace.I recommand it!